# Vba check if partial bolding in cell

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, cell

I'm generating XML from a list of text within a worksheet but I cant figure out how to check if the current cell has a bold word within it. What I need to do is check each cell in column A, read the text into a string, if I hit any bold words add the   tags around it.

I know you can read a cells contents character by character but not its formatting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a way that you can use to check if the cell has

1. Mixed characters which are bold. In this case it will return `NULL`
2. All characters are bold. In this case it will return `TRUE`
3. None of the characters are bold. In this case it will return `FALSE`

**Example**

[image]

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print Range("A1").Font.Bold
    Debug.Print Range("A2").Font.Bold
    Debug.Print Range("A3").Font.Bold
End Sub
```

[image]

To check if a cell has any bold character you can use this function as well (*Either from VBA or Worksheet*)

```
'~~> This is an additional function which will return...
'~~> TRUE if Cell has mixed/all chars as bold
'~~> FALSE if cell doesn't have any character in bold.
'~~> This can also be used as a worksheet function.
Function FindBoldCharacters(ByVal aCell As Range) As Boolean
    FindBoldCharacters = IsNull(aCell.Font.Bold)
    If Not FindBoldCharacters Then FindBoldCharacters = aCell.Font.Bold
End Function
```

**Screenshot**

[image]
[image]

And you can use `.Characters().Font.FontStyle` to check if each character is bold or not. Use the above Range `A1` example.

```
Sub Sample()
    For i = 1 To Len(Range("A1").Value)
        Debug.Print Range("A1").Characters(i, 1).Font.FontStyle
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Screeenshot**

[image]

**Modified Code**

```
Sub Sample()
    For i = 1 To Len(Range("A1").Value)
        If Range("A1").Characters(i, 1).Font.FontStyle = "Bold" Then
            Debug.Print "The " & i & " character is in bold."
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Sid, I get your `Character` code, but Im unclear what `FinBoldCharacters` is doing or how is it called?

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification using https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout post.  (I would have put it in a comment but too many characters).

Call it inside your sub via:

```
strTempText = isItBold(frBook.Worksheets(arraySys(x, 1)).Range("H" & y))
If strTempText <> "XXX" Then
 Debug.Print strTempText
End If
```

And the function.

```
Function isItBold(aCell As Range) As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim Sentence_Length As Integer
  Dim checkText As String

  Sentence_Length = Len(aCell)
  checkText = ""

  For i = 1 To Sentence_Length
    If aCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True Then
      checkText = checkText & aCell.Characters(i, 1).text
    End If
  Next i
  If Len(checkText) < 1 Then
    isItBold = "XXX"
  Else
    isItBold = checkText
  End If

End Function
```