# Replace formatted text in Excel field

Tags: vba, excel, formatting, format

I have created a simple excel tool to format an input as html output.
I simply replace special characters in the input and wrap some tags around it (with functions - no VBA).

Simplified Example:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(
     'Input'!$A30,
"À", "&Agrave;"),
```

The problem: I would like to detect **bold text** in the input fields (in this case $A30).
If there is bold text **somewhere** in the field, it should be wrapped with `"<b></b>"` in the output.

Is there a possibility to do this with Excel functions?
If not with excel functions, how would I do it in VBA?

Comment: Check out this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209572/vba-check-if-partial-bolding-in-cell).  I believe that you will have to use VBA.

Comment: You'll be looking at a VBA mechanism as I don't think that's possible using the built-in functions