# Extract normal font to new cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple cells with bold font and normal font, I am looking to only extract the font that isn't bold to a new cell. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vba check if partial bolding in cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209572/vba-check-if-partial-bolding-in-cell)

Comment: Im able to extract bold text, but i want to extract the text that isn't bold; all i can find is bold text extraction

Comment: To find bold characters: bold `= True`, for non bold characters bold `= False` otherwise it's pretty much all the same -- you will have to do some work to adapt the code to suit your needs

Answer (score 1):

You can just do the reverse of what Siddarth was doing in the post I linked - for example:

[image: img1]

Using this:

```
Sub Test()

Dim mystring As String

For i = 1 To Len(Range("A1").Value)
    If Range("A1").Characters(i, 1).Font.FontStyle = "Regular" Then
        mystring = mystring & Mid(Range("A1").Value, i, 1)
    ElseIf Len(mystring) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print Trim(mystring)
        mystring = ""
    End If

    If i = Len(Range("A1").Value) Then
        Debug.Print Trim(mystring)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Returns:

[image]

Comment: I would use `Range("A1").Characters(i, 1).Text` instead of `Mid(Range("A1").Value, i, 1)`.  Or more precisely `With  Range("A1").Characters(i, 1)`  and `If .Font.FontStyle = "Regular" Then` and `mystring = mystring & .Text`.

Comment: I follow what you are saying, but running this on a test cell, I did not get the same results; any ideas

Comment: @B.Cole Can you provide a picture of your test cell in your original post?

Comment: I was able to get it to work changing the bolds in a previous script to false. Thanks for your help! You guys are awesome!